# How could I compare a string to a set of other strings

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, if-statement, string-comparison

So i have an if-statement, which should compare a String to one of these strings: "J", "O", "J_1", "Z"
I need the if statement to check, wether the string matches one of these.
I could do this using else if, but that would be against the DRY (dont repeat yourself) concept.
So do you have an idea if this can be done an other way, than with else if?

Comment: what do you mean by "match" ?

Comment: if the given String equals one of the 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `in` operator:

```
if string in ["J", "O", "J_1", "Z"]:
    print("Winner!")
```

Comment: Maybe better to use a `set`: `if string_ in {"J", "O", "J_1", "Z"}`

Comment: Maybe, but not for efficiency in such a small group.  Ipython's `%timeit` says the two are within .02 µs of each other.

Comment: Interesting, if you factor out the construction of the `list` or the `set`, the  set lookup goes much faster. Using a preconstructed set takes 65% of the time that a preconstructed list takes.

Comment: And I did the math wrong earlier. Instead of .02µs, the difference on my PC is .0008µs.

Comment: Well the set lookup is O(1) vs. O(n) for a list. Obviously not a big deal for such a small list.